# How to Disable my App from Appearing on Android Wear Devices?

Tags: android, wear-os

How to Disable my App from Appearing on Android Wear Devices?
It seems that my app integrates automatically with Android Wear (notifications mirroring) but I want to disable it...

Comment: What do you mean by appearing on Android Wear? Are you building a wear app as part of your application?

Comment: Are you asking about notifications? By default, all notifications from phone apps are mirrored over to Wear.

Comment: My question refers to the notifications mirroring.

Comment: What about disabling the Wear app from turning up on the Wear menu? For example I have an app I install on my Mobile, I use it there, but don't want it to be installed on my Wear or be able to disabled from Wear menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your app's [phone] notification from being mirrored to Android Wear, call `setLocalOnly(true)` on the `Notification.Builder` (or `NotificationCompat.Builder`, if you're targeting SDK < 20) that you use to create the notification.

For example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder bob = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(content)
    .setLocalOnly(true);
```

(the last line is the important one)

Documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLocalOnly(boolean)

Comment: Perhaps because the Gear S3 runs Tizen, not Android Wear? IOW, it's not relevant to this question & answer.